# How do you preview a view containing a binding to its parent view's state?

Tags: swiftui

I present this view as a sheet from its parent view

```
struct NamesView: View {
    @Binding var match: Match

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since the `match` source of truth is in the parent view presenting this `NamesView` sheet, when the view is constructed I pass in a `$match` binding and data flows as intended.

However, when constructing this view in a preview provider

```
struct NamesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NamesView()
    }
}
```

the compiler says that `NamesView()` expects a `match` argument of type `Binding<Match>` (`Match` being the parent view presenting this view as a sheet). I'm not sure what would be a good way to proceed from here or if this is a limitation of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want only constant preview, then it can be

```
struct NamesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            NamesView(match: .constant(Match()))
        }
    }
```

if you want it in live, the it can be

```
struct NamesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    struct BindingTestHolder: View {
        @State private var testedMatch = Match()
        var body: some View {
            NamesView(match: $testedMatch)
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        BindingTestHolder()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a better solution for live previews. See .variable above.

Comment: thanks for the tweak. Have been searching for the answer for long. @asperi

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct NamesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            NamesView(match:.constant(Match()))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this in depth [here](https://michaellong.medium.com/swiftui-binding-extensions-b6a9f27d2858?sk=1cd091e8e3dcdbffb1459e38aacd8ec7), but the short version is simply to add the following extension:

```swift
extension Binding {
    public static func variable(_ value: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
        var state = value
        return Binding<Value> {
            state
        } set: {
            state = $0
        }
    }
}
```

And then do...

```swift
struct NamesView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NamesView(match: .variable(Match()))
    }
}
```

This lets you actually mutate the value, useful when doing live previews in Xcode 14.