# Preview for a View isn't compiling for Binding<[String]>

Tags: swiftui, combine

Here's the View's Signature:

[image]

Here's the attempt to create a preview:

[image]

I've been trying to satisfy the compiler.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60632545/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI @Binding Initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685964/swiftui-binding-initialize) You should be using `.constant(<Value Here>)`, something like `.constant([""])` instead of `$list`.

Comment: Preview is a static variable so list has to be as well. You also need to give it an initial value ‘@State static var list =  [String]()’

Answer (score 0):

I tried three of the suggestions. 
The 'static' option (via LuLuGaGa) was the best:

[image]