# SwiftUI Preview not working with Binding<Bool>

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct PremiumStoreSheetView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @Binding var didSelectPass: Bool
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PremiumStoreNavigationView()
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                Spacer()
                PremiumStoreItemVIew(didSelectPass: $didSelectPass, premiumItem: premiumStoreItems[0])
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW
struct PremiumStoreSheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var didSelectPass = false
    static var previews: some View {
        PremiumStoreSheetView(didSelectPass: $didSelectPass)
    }
}
```

My Preview isn't working. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Diagnostics shows

```
missing argument for parameter 'didSelectPass' in call

----------------------------------------

SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "BrainDrainExtreme"

missing argument for parameter 'didSelectPass' in call
```

Comment: `PremiumStoreSheetView(didSelectPass: .constant(false))`

Comment: The `State` works only in context of view, PreviewProvided is not view. If you need to test dynamic binding in preview use approach like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60632545/12299030.